# How to transform two Objects into one overview in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am currently struggling with the formatting of a map operation on two object arrays in Javascript.

So lets say we have two arrays:

```js
var customer = [
  { "Name": "Thomas", "Address": "example street 34", "customerID": 1 },
  { "Name": "Alica", "Address": "example street 24", "customerID": 2 },
  { "Name": "John", "Address": "example bouelvard 4", "customerID": 3 }
]

var orders = [
  { "Product": "iPhone 12", "Amount": 2, "customerID": 1 },
  { "Product": "charger", "Amount": 1, "customerID": 1 },
  { "Product": "screen protection", "Amount": 5, "customerID": 2 }
]
```

I want to have a result array so that when I print it out, I have an overview over customers with their orders in this way:

```js
{
  customer: {
    "Name": "Thomas",
    "Address": "example street 34",
    "customerID": 1,
  },
  order: [
    {
      "Product": "iPhone 12",
      "Amount": 2,
      "customerID": 1
    },
    {
      "Product": "charger",
      "Amount": 1,
      "customerID": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

So I basically did a map function and searched for orders with the same customer id.

```js
let overview = customers.map(element1 => ({ ...element1, : [...(orders.filter(element => element.customerID === element1.customerID))] }));
```

This is what I get:

```js
{
  "Name": "Thomas",
  "Address": "example street 34",
  "customerID": 1,
  "order": [[Object], [Object]]
}
```

How do I get the "customer:" before the output of the customer objects and why do I get the Object output in my order array?

Comment: `element1, : [` will throw a syntax error. Did you forget to add `order:` in your attempt?

Comment: All you need to do is add keys for your new object :`({
  customer: { ...element1
  },
  orders: [...(orders.filter(element => element.customerID === element1.customerID))]
})`

Comment: @Eldar thank you!! I now at least can write the "customer" before but I still get [[object]] on my orders.Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: That is just how it is displayed in the console you are using. If you log `JSON.stringify(overview, null, 4)`, you should see the full objects.

Answer (score 0):

try with that:

```
customer.map(element1 => (
   {...element1, order: orders.filter(element => element.customerID === element1.customerID)}
)))
```

You were missing 'order' key and also don't need to spread since filter returns an array (empty if nothing filtered)

[image]

Comment: I think that's a typo while posting here because in their current output they have `"order":`

Comment: @adiga you're right, updated

Comment: I wasn't nitpicking the typo. I'm just saying they are NOT missing a key in their actual code. Because, they are getting the output. So, that typo just happened when they pasted here. Their actual issue is they want `customer` to be nested object

Answer (score 0):

First you can create map from `orders` array where `customerId` will be key and array with all orders belonging to one customer will be map value.

Next is initialising empty `results` array and iterating `customers` array. While iterating, push new object to `results` array. New object should contain 2 fields, `customer` and `order`. `customer` is object from iteration and `order` is map value which you get from previously generate map using `customer.customerID` as map key.

This way, performance are increased because fetching data from Map data structure has O(1) time complexity. Using filter method to find all orders for specific customer is time consuming with complexity O(n).

```js
const customers = [{"Name": "Thomas", "Address": "example street 34", "customerID": 1},{"Name": "Alica", "Address": "example street 24", "customerID": 2}, {"Name": "John", "Address": "example boulevard 4", "customerID": 3}];

const orders = [{"Product": "iPhone 12", "Amount": 2, "customerID": 1},{"Product": "charger", "Amount": 1, "customerID": 1},{"Product": "screen protection", "Amount": 5, "customerID": 2}];

const ordersMap = new Map();
for (const order of orders) {
    const { customerID } = order;

    const mapValue = ordersMap.get(customerID);

    if (mapValue) {
        mapValue.push(order);
    } else {
        ordersMap.set(customerID, [order]);
    }
}

const results = [];
for (const customer of customers) {
    results.push({
        customer,
        order: ordersMap.get(customer.customerID),
    });
}

console.log(results)
```

Comment: I think using a map like this is certainly more efficient than iterating the entire orders array for every customer (as shown in the question code). Can you provide an explanation for your code (code-only answers are not appropriate on SO — see [answer]). You can simplify this by using a map of customers instead of orders: https://tsplay.dev/Nd2JdW

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Also, please read: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @jsejcksn thank you for your feedback. I will prepare better when answering on SO next time. I saw your solution in typescript and I appreciate your time writing it and sharing it with us, including me.  In your solution, I saw you used `const result = [...map.values()];` to create final results. I think that is unnecessary iteration that consumes time, because you have 3 iterations for creating final results and I think this can be done in 2 iterations.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74899831/how-to-transform-two-objects-into-one-overview-in-javascript/74900080?noredirect=1#comment132187910_74900080) "_[it] can be done in 2 iterations_": @MihajloNikolic You're right about that. You can edit your answer to provide an explanation here — you don't need to wait until "next time"!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:

```
let overview = customer.map(customer => ({
    customer,
    order: orders.filter(order => customer.customerID === order.customerID)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are so close! So very close. You can rename `customer` to `customers` just to avoid confusion the `element1` becomes `customer` and the rest is as shown below:

```js
const 
    customers = [ { "Name": "Thomas", "Address": "example street 34", "customerID": 1 }, { "Name": "Alica", "Address": "example street 24", "customerID": 2 }, { "Name": "John", "Address": "example bouelvard 4", "customerID": 3 } ],
    orders = [ { "Product": "iPhone 12", "Amount": 2, "customerID": 1 }, { "Product": "charger", "Amount": 1, "customerID": 1 }, { "Product": "screen protection", "Amount": 5, "customerID": 2 } ],
    
    custOrders = customers
        .map(
            customer => 
            ({
                customer,
                orders:orders
                    .filter(order => order.customerID === customer.customerID)
            })
        );
        
        
        
console.log( custOrders );
```